# ¿Cómo puedo proteger el código de Ionic 3 en una PWA publicada en internet?

Tags: ionic3, seguridad, consola, encriptación, pwa

Utilizo Ionic 3 con Firebase, pero cuando publico una PWA en internet, si alguien accede a la consola de desarrollador, puede ver todo el código, esto incluye las cadenas de conexión, etc. Esto es sumamente inseguro.
¿Cómo puedo ocultar estos archivos o hacer que el código sea ilegible?

Espero me puedan ayudar, de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La APIKEY identifica su proyecto Firebase en los servidores de Google. No es un riesgo de seguridad que alguien lo sepa. De hecho, es necesario que lo sepan para poder interactuar con su proyecto Firebase.

Si desea obtener información sobre cómo proteger todos los datos de acceso a sus servicios back-end de Firebase, lea la documentación sobre las [reglas de seguridad de Firebase .](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules)